# Points of discontinuity of Rational Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

**Question:**

Write all the points where $\cfrac{n^2-9n+20}{n^4-n^3-3n^2+n+2}$ is discontinuous.Provide the answer in simplest form.

**My Approach:**

Should I convert the numerator and denominator into its respective product form and try to cancel them? I am not getting any idea. Any help or guidance to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: To be exact, this function is continuous everywhere in its domain. However, I think the task is meant in a way so that your approach is perfectly fine: try to find the product form.

Comment: Someone had posted the product form.I was going to ask you to look at his answer but I see now that answer has already been down voted and deleted.I don't know the reason however.

Comment: @M.Winter I agree with your answer but I have noticed a strange thing that inspite of so many answers given by the users,none of them are getting up voted.I am going to wait for sometime and if there is no answer with 1 or greater upvotes then I am going to upvote and accept your answer .

Comment: Dont worry, you are right about being sceptic. Take your time, or even better, try to solve the problem using the hints and post your answer or at least an attempt. We then can help you to check or to fix it. If the hints are not clear to you, then explain what exactly you do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rational Root Theorem and synthetic division on the denominator. You will find 2 distinct factors with multiplicity 1 and a third with multiplicity 2.

Comment: Can you show a bit of working?

Comment: Possible rational roots come from the factors of "2" (p) and the factors of the leading coefficient of "1" (q).  Thus +/- 2 and 1 are possible rational roots. Test these 4 roots using synthetic division and obtaining a remainder of zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You should try to find the product form: $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots (x-a_n)$.

My tip is that the $a_i$'s are exactly the zeros of the polynomials. You should know how to find the zeros of a quadratic equation. Also you can try some simple numbers for the more complex polynomial.

**Example**. The polynomial $x+x^2$ has the zeros $0$ and $-1$, hence the product form is
$$(x-(-1))(x-0)=(x+1)x.$$

Try to apply this to your problem.

---

*Note*:$\;$
Sometimes the product form described above does not exactly equal the polynomial (if there is zero of multiplicity $>2$), but you should not care about this for now.